# pgfplots - Connecting max Values with new Line Curve

Tags: pgfplots, plot, maximum-values

I need to create a plot showing a curve, which is connecting the peaks of other curves.

Like the drawn black curve in the following picture:
[image: Black Line is the needed curve.]

The other curves are created by the following formula and are only here for reference:
`{1/sqrt((1+1/1-1/(x^2*1))^2+(\Qe)^2*(1/x-x)^2)}`

My formula has two variables. One is changing in respect to x, and the value of the other one doesn't really matter. This formula creates different maximum for different \Qe. The real \Qe doesn't matter I only need the max. value for each x. With x being the important variable, which is also being displayed.

Any idea appreciated.

Edit: Here is my approach how I draw the curves:

```
\documentclass{article}
% package for creating plots
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
% import logic images
\usetikzlibrary {circuits.logic.IEC}
% package to create diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzset{font={\fontsize{10pt}{12}\selectfont}}
\begin{document}
% -----------------------------


\begin{figure}[tb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel = {$\gls{symb:fn}$},
            ylabel = {$\gls{symb:Mg}(\gls{symb:fn})$},
            xmin = 0.2,
            xmax = 2,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 2
            ]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Qe}{0}
            \addplot[
                samples=500,
                color=green
             ]{1/sqrt((1+1/1-1/(x^2*1))^2+(\Qe)^2*(1/x-x)^2)};
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Qe}{1}
            \addplot[
                samples=500,
                color=blue
             ]{1/sqrt((1+1/1-1/(x^2*1))^2+(\Qe)^2*(1/x-x)^2)};
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\Qe}{3}
            \addplot[
                samples=500,
                color=red
             ]{1/sqrt((1+1/1-1/(x^2*1))^2+(\Qe)^2*(1/x-x)^2)};
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Qe}{10}
            \addplot[
                samples=500,
                color=pink
             ]{1/sqrt((1+1/1-1/(x^2*1))^2+(\Qe)^2*(1/x-x)^2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First solve for the closed (or parametric) form of the curve, then plug it into TikZ. Alternatively use something else to generate list of points then plug it into TikZ

Comment: I have found a solution to draw these curves individually (added in the question), but I can't figure out how to connect the maximum values.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the formula can't easily be derived and would result into a lengthy equation in order to get the first derivative. That's why I'd like to get the result by checking the max values of the results (approximation).

Comment: Okay, not sure if TikZ is that smart (to numerically compute the maximum of each curve), and that would be terribly slow anyway. Better use Mathematica or something else to just generate a table of values.